# MATLAB uimenus flash occasionally

Tags: user-interface, matlab

I have a figure with uimenus added to it (but MenuBar is off, so it's only my menus), each with one level of child menu items, such as the usual File, Edit, and Help menus. Sometimes the uimenus will flash, as if I had pressed "alt", used the arrow keys to highlight each item, then pressed "alt" again to cancel the menu selection. I have not figured out a pattern to when this happens, but I'm noticing it after clicking a uipushtool or choosing a uimenu. It does not happen every time, or it's happening so fast that it doesn't paint the window. I'm seeing this in R2010b.

Has anyone else seen this, and do you know what can be done to stop it? It's really distracting and makes the program look unprofessional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the culprit while digging around in the Java objects of a GUI under development. If you use [findjobj](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects) to retrieve the Java object corresponding to an HG object, it may cause the menu flashing behavior I was seeing. In particular, it happens when findjobj is processing the menu objects. This can be disabled using the `'nomenu'` option, which is the default for containers.

I was seeing menu flashes when calling `findjobj(gcbf, 'depth', 0)` to get the Java frame for the current figure. Changing that to `findjobj(gcbf, 'nomenu', 'depth', 0)` eliminated the flash.